# How do I pass a class object containing this and call a method from that class

Tags: c#, class, methods, instantiation

I created a formControlTracker class that handles form control tracking.  That seems to work as expected as is.  Now, I would like to access the public string[] getDirtyControls() method from within formControlTracker class when the save button is pressed.  I tried to access cTracker.getDirtyControls(), bus as the code stands, I think the class formControlTracker that I instantiated is outside of the scope. How do I access the getDirtyControls() method without having to re-instantiate the formControlTracker class?

Code snippet:

```
public partial class settingsForm : Form
{
    public settingsForm()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        settingsTabControl.Appearance = TabAppearance.Buttons;
        settingsTabControl.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
        settingsTabControl.ItemSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0,1);

        formControlTracker cTracker = new formControlTracker(this);

        wLogSettingsFormProperties settingsFormProp = new wLogSettingsFormProperties();

    }

    public void lDirtyControls()
    {

        /*foreach (string con in cTracker.getDirtyControls())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(con);
        }*/
    }

    public void saveSettingsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lDirtyControls();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it a field in the class

```
public partial class settingsForm : Form
{
    private formControlTracker _cTracker;

    public settingsForm()
    {
        //set the field value in the constructor.
        _cTracker = new formControlTracker(this);

    }

    public void lDirtyControls()
    {
        //use the field variable here
        /*foreach (string con in _cTracker.getDirtyControls())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(con);
        }*/
    }
}
```

Read here for more information about fields in c#: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx